# Why are there two different ways to use it?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

the same component is stored in state and ref respectively, but the calling methods of the two are different.

```
export default function getAsyncComponent(load) {
    const AsyncComponent = () => {
    const [component, setComponent] = useState(null)
    const com = useRef(null)

    const loadComponent = async () => {
      const _component = await load()
      
      com.current = _component.default
      setComponent(_component.default)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
      loadComponent()
    }, [])

    console.log(component, com.current)

    const Com = com.current

    return (
      <div>
        // Both ways are works.
        {component ? component : null}
        {Com ? <Com /> : null}
      </div>
    )
  }

  return <AsyncComponent />
}
```

print:

```
{$$typeof: Symbol(react.element), type: 'div', key: null, ref: null, props: {…}, …}

and

ƒ IndexPage() {
    return ((0,react_jsx_runtime__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.jsxs)("div", { children: [(0,react_jsx_runtime__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.jsx)("img", { className: _index_less__WEBPACK_I…
```

The use of getAsyncComponent is like this.

```
function App() {
  return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route
            path="/"
            element={getAsyncComponent(() => import('src/pages/index'))}
          />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
  )
}
```

Are the above two calling methods different?

react@18.1

react-router-dom@6.3

Comment: I don't understand the question. State and a ref are different types of storage, they're intended to be used for different purposes and are accessed differently, what exactly are you asking?

Comment: If you update state it will cause rerender. Updating ref wont have that effect.

Comment: @DBS I would like to ask why the values printed by component and com.current are not the same? Both are the same source.